# How to create a settings menu where each row is clickable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve that my settings menu looks like this

http://pbrd.co/17CajAU

Now I started with a relative layout but I am not sure if this is the best way to solve this, also I do not know how to add the horizontal lines into this. I guess with an background image for each of my textviews.

For each line there will be a new view which will be shown.
Is there a better way?

Here is my code so far, without horizontal lines

```
<!-- HEADER -->

<include
    android:id="@+id/top_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/header" />

<!-- FOOTER -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- menu bar -->

    <include layout="@layout/footer" />
</LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/settings_screen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeft"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_info"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/acount_info"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="startAccountInfoAction"
        android:clickable="true"            
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Statistic"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/statistic" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Contact"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/contact" />                              

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/open_jobs_label"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/open_jobs_label" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_sendData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="startSendDataAction"
        android:src="@drawable/restart_upload_blau" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/send_error_label"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/send_error_label" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/btn_sendError"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:background="@null"
         android:onClick="startSendErrorAction"
         android:src="@drawable/error_srs_blau" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you could do this with a 'PrefernceActivity'. This method is more easier and more native to android. So your Settings menu will appear like a typical Android Settings Menu.  Tell me if this is good for you. I can help you in this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the menu to be like picture you just linked.
Just use a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"` and use background images for each component (row) to get the desired look and feel. Also use `9patch` as background so they can stretch and fit all types of devices size and density.